# how to create table from a range in excel sheet in MFC c++ , visual studio 2010?

Tags: range, worksheet, listobject

i am using visual studio 2010 ,MFC
i want to create table from a given range in excel using c++ code
but i am not able to do that

Range = A2:D4

oWorkSheets2007  =  oWorkBook2007.GetWorksheets();

oWorkSheet2007    =  oWorkSheets2007.GetItem(COleVariant((short)oTblObj.sheetNom));   // sheet 1

XLS2007::Range oRange2007 = oWorkSheet2007.GetRange(COleVariant(leftCell),COleVariant(rightCell));//
leftcell  =  A2 , rightcell = D4

XLS2007::Range orange1,orange2;

XLS2007::ListObjects  oListObjs  =   oWorkSheet2007 .GetListObjects();

XLS2007::ListObject Tblobj      =   oListObjs.Add( 1,COleVariant(Range),COleVariant((short)(0)) ,1,COleVariant(leftRange),COleVariant(L"TableStyleMedium1"));

oRange2007.Table(COleVariant(leftCell),COleVariant(rightCell));

it gives error in  line 8 , i am not able to create table